# PHP/MySQL Prepared statement not assigning a value to a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a prepared statement (select with joins) inside my php that seems to be assigning values to all but one of its variables:

```
$dbRating = "x";
$dbFavDate = "x";

if($stmt = $dbcon->prepare("
    SELECT i.*, u.username, r.rating, f.date_favorited
    FROM image i 
        INNER JOIN user u ON u.uid = ? 
        LEFT JOIN rating r ON r.iid = ? AND r.uid = ? 
        LEFT JOIN favorite f ON f.iid = ? AND f.uid = ? 
    WHERE i.iid = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("iiiiii", $qImageOwner, $qImageId, $uid, $qImageId, $uid, $qImageId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($dbIid, $dbOwnerUid, $dbTitle, $dbDescription, $dbFilename, $dbCatid, $dbDateCreated, $dbDateModified, $dbOwnerUsername, $dbRating, $dbFavDate);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

I have put this query into phpmyadmin directly and gotten back all expected values, so I know it's not the sql. I am getting all values returned as expected *except* for the $dbFavDate, for some reason this always displays as 'x' (the initial value I assigned to it before the query), while the $dbRating which is handled the same way returns the expected associated rating value. No errors are produced, it seems that variable is just not being assigned the actual value returned from the query?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
TE

Comment: using `$dbcon->prepare()` without being parametrized is not prevents you from SQL injection attack!

Comment: Am not familiar - reference link for how/what you mean? Also, any idea on the 'lost' variable value? EDIT: oh, right, I think I know what you're referring to - I was using that structure for inserts, but not selects. I will modify the code to reflect that, and let you know if that resolves the dropped variable value.

Comment: Updated the code in the initial post. Still having same problem - $dbFavDate is not being assigned a value...

Comment: `$stmt->execute();` should be before `$stmt->bind_result(..)` immediately after prepare.

Comment: Moved $stmt->execute() to after $stmt->bind_param() and before $stmt->bind_result(). Same result however. Updating code in ip to reflect change.

Answer (score -1):

Argh! Finally. It was neither a problem with the sql OR php. An if statement in the javascript was using

```
if (dbFavDate = 'x') {
```

rather than

```
if (dbFavDate == 'x') {
```

(>_<) !! Thanks for the input guys.